CoinSelection: GetSelectionAmount: m_value or effective_value
During the process of coin_selection, the method OutputGroup::GetSelectionAmount() is called for each txout during selection.  This method either returns the m_value or the effective_value.  Why would the m_value be useful instead of the effective_value during coin-selection?

m_effective_value is the value of the output minus the fees required to pay for spending it in an input. When using that, inputs are considered to be paying for themselves. However, if the subtract fee from output feature is being used, then this is no longer the case. The transaction's outputs will be paying the fees, so it is incorrect to consider the inputs as paying for themselves. As such, the real value, stored in m_value, needs to be used.

I see, thanks.  I didn't know about the subtract fee from output feature.  It sounds like it would be subtracted from the recipients output in this case.
